# New tires size on my Jeep compass

Tags: tires

I want to buy new tires but I want to know if It's ok if I put on my Jeep Compass tire size 205 65r16 insted of 205 70r16
Is there any real problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be fine. Your speedometer might be off by a little (it'll be a few km/h higher than your actual speed), but other than that, as long as you're replacing all 4 tires, there won't be any issues.

As @Moab mentions, your highway mileage may also decrease by a few %.

Comment: It will also put a pinch on fuel mileage.